# Inflating a view Vs formatting view items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, getview

So i have a listview that i want to populate with headers and a view layout with some images and some text.

What is the most performance efficient way to go about this?

Inflate a layout for the header and another for the normal view or use the same layout for both only with some formatting and re-formatting to achieve the goal?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each row will be the same layout format, then it would be better to have one layout that you inflate in your `getView()` method within the ListView adapter. When this View is inflated, you can than access the TextViews and ImageViews within the layout and configure them to how you would like. I believe that inflating only one view would provide for a quicker and more memory-effecient method.

Comment: Well to be honest the layout has 3 textviews and one imageview.

For the header i'm making 2 of the textviews and the imageview disappear and changing the background color and the other textview color and padding.

i then change it all back.

Comment: So, you can use `your_text_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`, `your_inflated_view..setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);`, etc. All those values can be changed programmatically. I would put some sort of flag in your adapter to notify that a view is either a header or a regular row, and check for this flag in your `getView()` method.

Comment: Yeah, i got that all covered to be honest, i just was unsure if i should be inflating a new layout for the header to optimize performance.